# Image Slider in IE

Tags: html, css, image, internet-explorer

That's the output of image slider in IE8 not alike to Opera, Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome. It must be center and has no margin or space in the left side. and also it doesn't move to next slide. How can I fix these problems. Please help me.

My CSS

```
#container3 {
height: 350px; width: 990px;
position: relative;    
padding: 0;
margin: 0;}

div#captioned-gallery {
width: 100%; height: 350px; padding: 15x 0 0 15px; margin: 0;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;  z-index: 5;
background-image: url(../images/slideshow-background.jpg);
}

figure {
padding-left: auto;
padding-right: auto;
margin: 0;
}
figure.slider {
position: relative;
width: 990px;
animation: 40s slidy infinite;
margin: 0;
}
figure.slider figure{
width: 990px;
height: 350px;
display: inline-block;
position:absolute;
}
figure.slider img {
min-width: 990px; min-height: 350px center;
max-width: 990px; max-height: 350px center;
padding: auto;
position: relative;
}
figure.slider figcaption {
position: absolute; bottom: 0;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
color: #fff;
width: 970px;
font-size: 11px; padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
text-align: justify;
padding-left: 10px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
figure.slider figcaption a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #25aee4;
font-size: 11px;
text-transform: none;   
}
figure.slider figcaption h3 {
color: #25aee4;
font-size: 13px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
'
```

Comment: min-height: 350px center; - not valid

Comment: @Dmitriy . Is there any code that is not valid? Please check.

Comment: Why `min-width: 990px; min-height: 350px center;
max-width: 990px; max-height: 350px center;` instead of `width:990px; height:350px;`?

Comment: @disinfor. Thanks I fixed it now.

Comment: Also, please post some HTML and tell us what code/plugin/script you're using to operate the slideshow.

Answer (score 0):

```
My HTML
<div id="container3">
    <div id="captioned-gallery">
            <figure class="slider">    
                <figure> 
                    <a href="w3school.com"><img src="images/Issue1-Message.jpg"/></a>
                    <figcaption><h3><b>ALAS OPLAS JOINS BKR INTERNATIONAL</b></h3><br/>Mr. Donnies T. Alas, Chairman/CEO and Ms. Marycris S. Oplas, Managing Partner of Alas Oplas & Co., CPAs receive a certificate of membership from BKR International effective May 1, 2014. Testimony of Alas Oplas & Co., CPAs' dedication to excellence and achievement in accounting profession, with adherence to strict professional standards and practices, while providing consistent high quality service to all our clients. <a href="#">read more&raquo;</a></figcaption>
                </figure>
                <figure>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/AlasOplas-BKR.jpg"/></a>
                    <figcaption><h3><b>ALAS OPLAS JOINS BKR INTERNATIONAL</b></h3><br/>Mr. Donnies T. Alas, Chairman/CEO and Ms. Marycris S. Oplas, Managing Partner of Alas Oplas & Co., CPAs receive a certificate of membership from BKR International effective May 1, 2014. Testimony of Alas Oplas & Co., CPAs' dedication to excellence and achievement in accounting profession, with adherence to strict professional standards and practices, while providing consistent high quality service to all our clients. <a href="#">read more&raquo;</a></figcaption>
                </figure>
                <figure>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/AlasOplas-BKR-conference.jpg"/></a>
                    <figcaption><h3><b>Independent Member of BKR International</b></h3><br/>Alas Oplas & Co., CPAs is an independent member of BKR International. RANKED IN THE TOP 5 OF ACCOUNTING ASSOCIATIONS, BKR INTERNATIONAL'S global accountants and advisors help businesses and entrepreneurs around the world. BKR International represents the combined strength of more than 160 independent accounting and business advisory firms in over 500 offices and 80 countries. <a href="#">read more&raquo;</a></figcaption>
                </figure>
                <figure>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/barentz.jpg"/></a>
                    <figcaption><h3><b>Barentz Strengthens by Opening an Office in the Philippines</b></h3><br/>September 6, 2013, was the birth of Barentz Philippines, Inc., an international leader in Sales, Marketing and Distribution of food ingredients, opened an office in the Philippines.<a href="#">read more&raquo;</a></figcaption>
                </figure>
                <figure>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/AuditAssuranceSeminar.jpg"/></a>
                    <figcaption><h3><b>Business Assurance Seminar</b></h3><br/>JUNE 20 & 21, 2014 - Mr. Donnies T. Alas, ACPAPP President join ACPAPP Negros Occidental Chapter the two-day seminar entitled “Business Assurance Seminar (BAS) 2” with guest speaker Ms. Rosemary D. De Mesa at LA Hall, Avenue Suites Hotel & Spa, Bacolod City. More than 35 Spa, Bacolod City. More than 35 participants earned 16 CPE units.<a href="#">read more&raquo;</a></figcaption>
                </figure>
            </figure>
    </div>
</div>
```